# The activity "MainMenu" is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml [Even though it is]

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, apk, android-manifest

So, I have encountered this error and now I can't even compile the code! I had to rename the package because, it wasn't able to upload the APK, because of it's default com.example[...] specificaton. Thus, I renamed the package according to this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7-bvkRthWM and everything messed up greatly.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml, as you can see the activity MainMenu is defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.done.samuelh.josethepig" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
     android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" - dark original background-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.done.samuelh.josethepig.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.done.samuelh.josethepig.Game"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my build.gradle...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.done.samuelh.josethepig"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Everything, but publishing the APK was working so well before that tutorial and now I am really stuck with a complete game...

How can I fix this obnoxious error?

Comment: Did you change any of your packages?

Comment: yes what is your project structure like

Comment: try changing this  android:name="com.done.samuelh.josethepig.MainMenu" to this  android:name=".MainMenu"

Comment: Thank you @dave but it appears that even though I synchronized, cleaned and rebuilt. As soon as I started typing new code to each of mentioned activities the error vanished. Seems like there is a bug in the AS and it isnt registering refactors.

Comment: Thank you @BidhanA, but have not edited any other packages. [see cmt above]

Comment: Thank you @Smashing, but have not edited any other packages. [see cmt above]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Closing and reopening the project in AS solved the issue for me.